# Product with a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

If $H \unlhd K \unlhd G$ and $P\unlhd G$ then does necessarily $HP \unlhd KP$?

I can see this is true using the correspondence theorem since $HP/P \unlhd KP/P$

I want to try direct and prove it directly using elements of $HP$ and $KP$ but I can't seem to get anywhere.

Let $x = hp_1 \in HP$ and $y = kp_2 \in KP$ then to show $yxy^{-1} \in HP$. Now $yxy^{-1} = kp_2hp_1p_2^{-1}k^{-1}$. I'm not sure how the elements commute to give the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$yxy^{-1} = kp_2hp_1p_2^{-1}k^{-1}=kp_2hk^{-1}(kp_1p_2^{-1}k^{-
1})=kp_2k^{-1}(khk^{-1})(kp_1p_2^{-1}k^{-1})=(khk^{-1})(kh^{-1}k^{-1})(kp_2k^{-1})(khk^{-1})(kp_1p_2^{-1}k^{-1})= h^{k^{-1}}(kp_2k^{-1})^{khk^{-1}}(p_1p_2^{-1})^{k^{-1}} \in HP.$

Another way to prove this is observing that in general if $N \unlhd G$, and $H \leq G$, then $N_G(H)N \subseteq N_G(HN)$.

Since in your case $K \subseteq N_G(H)$ we get $KP \subseteq N_G(H)P \subseteq N_G(HP)$, that is $KP$ normalizes $HP$.

Final remark: we did *not* use the fact that $K$ is *normal* in $G$.